# How to check if byte array is .emf or .wmf format

Tags: java

I can check if byte array is a metafile image like wmf, emf using below java code

```
private boolean isMetaFileFormat(byte[] pictureData)
{
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try 
    {
        image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(pictureData));
        if(image != null)
            return false;           
    } 
    catch (Exception e){ }
    return true;
}
```

but how to specifically check if it is emf or wmf image?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Java Mime Magic Library` for easy and common way. [Download](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jmimemagic/jmimemagic/0.1.2)

```
MagicMatch match = Magic.getMagicMatch(your_byte_array);
String mimeType = match.getMimeType();

if(mimeType.equals("image/x-emf")) {
    //here is emf
}
if(mimeType.equals("image/x-wmf")) {
    //here is wmf
}
```

Answer (score 5):

WMF file's magic number is `0x9AC6CDD7`, EMF magic number is `0x01000000`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get image type from the byte array

```
byte[] pictureData = null;
    ImageInputStream stream;
    try {
        stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                pictureData));
        Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);
        while (readers.hasNext()) {
            ImageReader read = readers.next();
            read.getFormatName();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Comment: I tried ur code but ImageReader object has no values for byte array of embedded equation in word document:(

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html#getFormatName()